# How to display, split and merge PPT slides using angular

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, typescript

I am looking for a way to display, split and merge ppt slides in frontend using angular (typescript/JavaScript). Talking about split and merge, My idea is to collect slides from different ppts and merge them to produce a new ppt. I tried using aspose-cloud but the process is too complicated that I had to hit node server on each click.